# Is it possible to map the keys of a tuple to a union of number literals?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a tuple

```
type MyTuple = [string,number];
```

Now, I would like to get the union of all numeric keys for this tuple, i.e. `0 | 1`. I can do this:

```
type MyKeys = Exclude<keyof MyTuple, keyof unknown[]>;
```

which will return the type `"0" | "1"`, but that is a union of string literals. Is it possible to get a union of number literals instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, so I found the solution. Here it is:

```
type MyTuple = [string, string, string];
type KeysOfTuple = Exclude<Partial<MyTuple>['length'], MyTuple['length']>;
// KeysOfTuple = 0 | 2 | 1
```

Comment: Actually your solution is better. Just needed to exclude the tuple length